# How to put an alert in extension page action

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension that works on certain sites when the user visits a specific site an icon appears in the address bar, I would like to create a type of alert in the form of popup that appears on the screen when the user visits the specific website, I'm not satisfied just with someone icon can help me?

which is the aim of this extension?

My goal is to create an extension that alerts the user to access E-COMMERCE sites not recommended for shopping

My background

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

if (~tab.url.indexOf('specificsite.com.br')) {
chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for now, you can use [`notifications` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) to alert the user.

At some point in near future, `chrome.pageAction.openPopup()` will be a thing. As of now, it's [not promoted to Stable](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436489).

Comment: still do not understand, how do I notice appear when the user visits the site specific WHAT should I do? sorry for the questions I'm new to creating extensions could help me create?